# Detect value change in input field that is automatically populated by postal code lookup

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using a postal code lookup service on my site (https://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk). The script provides me with an input fields that accepts postal codes, address etc and then shows the appropriate results. Once I select the correct address it automatically populates the remaining input fields (house number, street etc), which I determined.

I want to validate those fields (show an icon to its right) if filled in correctly but the problem is that it doesn't detect the value change. If I click inside the populated input field again it does start the validation though.

I tried .change(), .bind(), keyup() and other events but can't get it to work. Any other ideas?

UPDATE: Here is the code:

```
$('#postcode').bind('blur', function(){
   validatePostCode();
});

function validatePostCode() {
  var postCode = $('#postcode').val();

  if( !alphaNumericRegex.test(postCode) ) {
    $('#postCodeWrap').find('.errorMessage').html('Must contain six characters.);
    $('#postCodeWrap').find('.validationSuccess').hide();
    $('#postcode').css('background', 'rgb(242, 222, 222)');
    $('#postcode').addClass('errorVisible');
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#postCodeWrap').find('.validationSuccess').show();
    $('#postCodeWrap').find('.errorMessage').html('');
    $('#postcode').css('background', '#FFFFFF');
    $('#postcode').removeClass('errorVisible');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should run your validation process upon population of your field cause no client event is triggered when updating info from javascript. If you could post your code it would be easier to help though...

Comment: You're not binding to anything ?

Comment: Hi Bartdude, I just posted some code. I try to run the validation process upon population but can't get it to work

Comment: @adeneo Oops, that's how I had it actually. I've been trying around for a while now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the value is changed programatically with JS, no event is triggered. You can trigger the event yourself when the first field is changed:

```
$('#first-field').on('change', function() {
    $('.the_rest_of_my_fields').trigger('change');
});
```